# Could not open url 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'

Tags: r

When I install new version of Rstudio (the latest version: 2022.02.3-492),
many packages that were previously installed do not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgA0t.jpg)

Also, **install.packages** does not work due to "cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'"

First, I checked **getOption("repos")** and it prints

```
CRAN 
"http://cran.rstudio.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE
```

Next, checked **sessionInfo()**, and it prints

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0 tools_4.2.0
```

Finally, checked my firewall blocker and allowed an application of RStudio R session.

However, none of them works.

It is making me crasy. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In RStudio Go to ***Tools*** -> ***Global Options*** and in the ***Packages*** tab uncheck the box "***use secure download method for HTTP***".

[Packages menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXvDh.png)